# How to do looping in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have source table named, tbl_account

| Policy_No | Old_Policy_No |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | C |
| C | D |
| D | Null |
| E | G |
| G | H |
| H | L |

I want to write query using looping to get this target result with condition Policy_no In (A, C, E, G)

| Policy_No | Old_Policy_No |
| --- | --- |
| A | D |
| C | D |
| E | L |
| G | L |

Please help me if anyone knows how to get the Query.

Comment: Why would you *want* to loop in SQL? SQL is a *set based* language, it excels at set based processes; a loop is the opposite to that.

Comment: @ThomA op might mean recursion

Comment: I thought that, @DaleK , but then why does E have a value of `G` and not `L`. Or why does `A` have a value of `D` and not `B`. The results are inconsistent.

Comment: I'm happy to vote to re-open if the question is fixed. Please read [ask].

Comment: I am so sorry for the result,
I have edit the result that i want

Comment: @DaleK yes it should be L, i am sorry. I have edit the value of result

Comment: Have you had a look at rCTEs? What *have* you looked at? What have you tried? What about your attempt(s) didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with a recursive query :

```
CREATE TABLE T_POLICIES
(Policy_No VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 Old_Policy_No VARCHAR(8))

INSERT INTO T_POLICIES VALUES
('A', 'B'),
('B', 'C'),
('C', 'D'),
('D', Null),
('E', 'G'),
('G', 'H'),
('H', 'L');

WITH
RECURSION AS
(SELECT Policy_No, Old_Policy_No, 1 AS STEP
 FROM   T_POLICIES AS P
 WHERE  Policy_No NOT IN(SELECT Old_Policy_No 
                         FROM   T_POLICIES
                         WHERE  Old_Policy_No IS NOT NULL) 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT R.Policy_No, P2.Old_Policy_No, STEP+1
 FROM   RECURSION AS R
        JOIN T_POLICIES AS P2
           ON R.Old_Policy_No = P2.Policy_No
 WHERE  P2.Old_Policy_No IS NOT NULL),
LAST_VERSION AS
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Policy_No ORDER BY STEP DESC) AS N
 FROM RECURSION)
SELECT Policy_No, Old_Policy_No
FROM   LAST_VERSION
WHERE  N = 1
```

[To read about recusive queries :](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/recursive-queries-in-sql1999-and-sql-server-2005)

Comment: looks correct but not what op wants(which isn't explained),,

Comment: @P.Salmon It is why I have post an url to a paper I wrote about 20 years back...